# Set AJAX content type header in request from IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, rest, content-type

Is it possible to set the http content-type request header to 'application/json' when sending a cross domain jquery ajax http request from Internet Explorer?

We're trying to hit a REST WCF service that interprets the content type from the request header when formatting the response. Right now, no matter what we put in the request header it is always returning the data in XML format.

We've tried using the jquery.iecors.js plugin which extends the jquery ajax call to use the XDomainRequest object but that is still ignoring the content-type that is set in our jquery ajax call.

Here's what our ajax call looks like:

```
makeGETRequest: function (requestUrl) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: requestUrl,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType:'json',
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just pass the content-type as one of your parameters to the `.ajax` method:

```
var retval = jQuery.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately we're still getting xml back from our service call.

Comment: Can you post the response you're getting back?  Especially the response header and part of the body.

Comment: You should also check that the service you are talking to is configured to response with JSON.  See [Suhas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7479418/1292052)

Comment: Our problem was that the 'Accept' header needed to be set to 'application/json'. You were first to answer the question I asked so thank you for that, turns out I didn't ask the right question for what we were facing :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could use the `contentType` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/someurl',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Request sent:

```
POST /someurl HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 13
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

{"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately we're still getting xml back from our service call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, turns out we need to set the 'Accept' header