# Wrong Content-Type being substituted for fetch http request

Tags: javascript, json, http, fetch

I have this code on client:

```
return fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/authenticate', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'admin',
    }),
});
```

When i send this request for some reason Content-Type is substituted to `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. This makes my server side fail the request as it only accepts `application/json` requests. What am i doing wrong here?
I am using Chrome 51 and here is my request:

[image]

EDIT:
When I remove `JSON.strigify()` Content-Type and Request payload are also being omitted.
Here is an example:

[image: Result without JSON.stringify()]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890662/set-ajax-content-type-header-in-request-from-ie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have set `mode: 'no-cors',` so you cannot set `'Content-Type'` to `'application/json'`. It isn't one of the [safe values for Content-Type](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header).